# readonly file on linux

Tags: files, readonly, lock

I want to lock a file(or read-only) so that anybody on server can't modify it. I find `chattr` command on Linux but I didn't use it for some reason.

I am using `mount --bind file.log file.log`, but after some day I need to unlock this file and use `umount -l` and `rm -rf file.log` but show this error

> Device or resource busy.

When I reboot the server problem seems to be solved after reboot. Can you help me without reboot solve this problem?

Comment: Well, as Luis already mentioned, you should use your system as it is expected to be used. I also don't see why `mount --bind file.log file.log` should "lock" a file to be read only. Use `chattr` or `chown` and `chmod` for this task. If you can't unmount the bind mount, check with `lsof file.log` which process is accessing it and end that process. Then try to unmount it again. But I don't think that a bind mount will "lock" a file.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the problem correctly, what about if you `chown root:root file`, so that user `root` owns the file and then `chmod 444 file`, to disable any writing to it.  This way, only `root` will be able to modify the file.

Comment: Thank you , but i dont use chmod and chown for some reason.

Comment: fuser -m file.log  will list all processes which are using the file . Then kill those processes to umount the file system . fuser -km file.log can also be used to kill the processes associated with the file.